# Problems with close, read & write filedescriptors while cross-compiling on x86 Linux using Eclipse

Tags: cross-compilation

Even though I am including `<fcntl.h>`, I keep getting

```
'write' was not declared in this scope
'read' was not declared in this scope
'close' was not declared in this scope
```

even though the `open()` function works just fine, and it compiles fine for x86.

I am following the instructions at [[Howto] Cross compile using Eclipse](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=10739) and running Eclipse on a VM (oSX as host) with Ubuntu 12.04.

My Project Properties are:

```
CrossSettings, Path: tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin
Cross GCC Compiler, Command: arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-gcc
Cross G++ Compiler, Command: arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++
Cross G++ Linker, Command: arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

This is the simplified source that gives the error for the "close":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;
int fd;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile for x86 with gcc/g++ it works...

Comment: Could you try compiling this without Eclipse? Just add your crosscompiler binaries to PATH, like this: `export PATH=$PATH:<pathtoyourcrosscompiler>` where <pathtoyourcrosscompiler> is *full path* to arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++. Then try: `arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o /tmp/test <yoursourcefile>', where <yoursorucefile> is a path to the file containing your program. Paste the output here, please. Also please try to change your path to *full path*.

Comment: Have you got anywhere on this problem? If so, please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We're (at least I) am going through the site to try and get the question:answer ratio up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this compiling under x86 is a fluke. According to the [read manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), it's part of unistd.h. Same for close() and write(). Only open is declared in fcntl.h. I think you'll need to include both:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

If you're planning to use C++ streams, you'll also need to include fstream.

```
#include <fstream>
```